# Set inclusion path that working with explicit relative paths

Tags: php

I know that this line:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/my/other/path');
```

add `'/my/other/path'` to the list of directories where `require`, `include` (and others) functions look for files.

But this option is valid only for path specified without `./` or `../` at the begin of path. For example:

```
// I would include /my/other/path/Zend.php
require('Zend.php'); // it works 
require('./Zend.php'); // it does not works 

// or if I would include /my/other/Zend.php
require('../Zend.php'); // still does not works
```

However I'm searching a way for do it

NOTE: This is for an eccentric project. In this case I cannot modify the file with include and require functions.

Comment: What don't you just use fill path always `require(ZEND_PATH . '/Zend.php');`

Comment: `eccentric` looks like a big word .. did not bother reading that part :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, the only thing you can do in order to achieve that is [chdir](http://php.net/manual/es/function.chdir.php): you set the current working directory to one that fits the relative routes.